# How to select values that correspond with a max date in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, max, min

I am trying to write a query that takes both the max and min values from a table group by id. Basically, I have a table that adds renewals for new annual amounts off an existing contract_id as such:

```
customer_id | contract_id | start_date | end_date   | revenue
6           | 125         | 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-31 | 10,000
6           | 126         | 2012-01-01 | 2013-12-31 | 5,000
6           | 125         | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31 | 12,000
6           | 126         | 2014-01-01 | 2015-12-31 | 8,000
```

What I want to take the minimum start_date, the maximum end_date, and the corresponding revenue for that end_date, grouped by contract_id for a given customer_id.

So, the query would ideally return:

```
customer_id | contract_id | start_date | end_date   | revenue
6           | 125         | 2012-01-01 | 2013-12-31 | 12,000
6           | 126         | 2012-01-01 | 2015-12-31 | 8,000
```

I can get the max stuff, but I'm having trouble pulling in both MAX and MIN in the same query. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can there be tied max dates for the same contract_id? If so, which value do you want?

Comment: That should almost never happen, but if it did, I guess I'd want the max(row_id). I didn't include that in the table because I didn't think about this case, nice catch!

Comment: I also have a created_at datetime field, so I could use the max(date_created) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this Query also see the screenshot for verification (*see image 1*)

```
SELECT r.`contract_id`,r.`start_date`,
(SELECT sub_r.`end_date` FROM `table` sub_r where sub_r.`contract_id` = r.`contract_id` 
ORDER BY sub_r.`revenue` DESC limit 1 )
AS `end_date`,
(SELECT sub_r.`revenue` FROM `table` sub_r where sub_r.`contract_id` = r.`contract_id` 
ORDER BY sub_r.`revenue` DESC limit 1 )
AS `revenue` 
FROM `table` r GROUP BY r.`contract_id`;
```

> Image 1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a union to enable you to split the query into two halves - one for "max" and one for "min", and don't use the max of min functions; sort the data by the target field instead and get the top row.

```
select * from (
  select * from mytable
  where customer_id = ?
  order by start_date, created_at
  limit 1) x
union all
select * from (
  select * from mytable
  where customer_id = ?
  order by end_date desc, created_at desc
  limit 1
) y
```

Note: This will always return 2 rows, even if the "min" and "max" rows are the same row (in cases where there is only one row for the customer)

#### Edited:

Also ordering by `created_at` to break ties (from comments added later)

Comment: Unfortunately, the limit 1 creates a return of only one row and not two. Could it be we need some sort of grouping?

Comment: @user882134 No, you will get **TWO** rows from this query. There's a union of two `limit 1` queries, each subquery will return one row

Comment: Sorry, when I run (select * from contract_renewal where contract_id = 125), I get two rows returned. When I run (select * from 
  (select * from contract_renewal
  where contract_id = 125
  order by start_date, created_at) x
limit 1
union all
select * from 
  (select * from contract_renewal
  where contract_id = 125
  order by end_date desc, created_at desc) y
limit 1;), I get one row returned.

Comment: I figured it out. The "limit 1" needs to go inside the inner query --

select * from 
  (select * from mytable
  where customer_id = ?
  order by end_date desc, created_at desc) y
limit 1 

vs

select * from 
  (select * from mytable
  where customer_id = ?
  order by end_date desc, created_at desc limit 1) y

The second one works as you stated.

Comment: Thanks. I dont have a mysql installation to check this. I edited the answer to reflect your comment

Comment: Ugh, sorry I spoke to soon. It does return two rows but not with the appropriate values grouped by contract_id. Your query should work, but it's missing something. Sorry.

Comment: I missed the "grouped by contract". I'll have a look at it later